# Postgres query to using group by and order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which has several columns in which I want to group it by one column within this group i want to apply group by other column and the need top 3 result from every group
example

```
col1 col2  col3
1    1.9   2.6
1    1.2   3.5 
1    2.1   4.1
2    3.2   3.3
2    2.5   3.5
3    1.1   1.8
3    2.1   1.9
```

Result:

```
col1   col2    col3
1      1.2     2.6
1      1.9     3.5
1      2.1     4.1
2      2.5     3.3
2      3.2     3.5
3      1.1     1.8
3      2.1     1.9
```

I want the result from this table which will be groped on col1 and within every group and sorted on col2 and top 3 from every group based on col2

Answer (score 1):

this is a typical "greatest N per group" problem which is usually solved using window functions:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (
   select col1, col2, col3,
          row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as rn
   from the_table
) t
where rn <= 3
order by col1, col2;
```

Comment: =>it is not grouping based on col1 ,I want the result grouped on col1 and ordering should be done on individual group only not on the whole table

Comment: @shashiranjan: sorry I have no idea what you mean with that. The ordering **is** done on the individual groups (that's the `partition by col1` clause for the window partition). As your sample data and the expected output are absolutely identical it's hard to tell what you really want